# jQuery Isotope: Custom layout based on active sort

Tags: sorting, layout, jquery-isotope

I'm using [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) and wondering if this scenario is even possible:

**Example:**

There are three categories within a portfolio to sort by: Branding (B), Identity (I) and Websites (W). The columns go up to five wide.

Initially, all display in a random order (which is good):

```
B B I B W
I W I W B
W I I
```

When choosing a sort order, the following occurs (say I choose Branding (B)):

```
B B B B I
W I W I W
W I I
```

Are there options within Isotope that allow for a "break" to occur after the selected sorting option? For example:

```
B B B B
I W I W I
W W I I
```

So, for the example above, the B's would be in their own row group, with everything else following after.

The custom layout mode for Category Row seems to provide a general direction, but I'm not sure  of a way to call out the selected items and then just everything else.

Comment: I have a starter example up for review: http://jsfiddle.net/bloom/NMstf/2/

Comment: You are on the right track, as far as I understand your layout concept - just use the categoryRows custom layout mode and operate with "invisible" elements so that, like in your third example, four Bs seem to fill the first row. This, however, can only work as long as you are using a fixed-width container, because eventually, other elements will "sneak" up to where the B-line is. After all, that's the whole idea about Isotope - to design fluid and responsive layouts across devices. PS: having elements "missing" like in what you desire to do with the Bs may puzzle viewers.